# Eclipse Tycho build issue

Tags: eclipse-rcp, tycho, p2

I Created RCP-Product(based on 4.16 eclipse) having 200+ plugins and the product configuration file is based on plugins and I am building my tool with tycho(1.7.0). I want to warp plugins at root-level from tycho build so that I can upgrade these plugins.

For this I have added installMode="root" for plugins,

e.g. `<plugin id="com.myproduct.commands.plugin" installMode="root"/>`

Build is successful but when I launch the product from build and check install-details, plugins are not installed at root-level.

Since I cannot migrate my whole application to feature, can anyone help me how I can wrap plugins at root-level.

Comment: installMode is only supported on features

Comment: can we achieve this by p2.inf

Comment: I believe installMode is only for features, you can't do this on a plug-in based RCP. Changing to using features is very straightforward.